# Checking the length of an attribute of a class for validation

Tags: python, class, attributes

In the below code, when creating the object circle in the last line, I want to validate that the center has only 2 elements in the list. The below code gives an error 'object of type 'Point' has no len()'. How do I correctly validate the attribute?

```
class Point():
    pass

class circle():
    def __init__(self,center, radius):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius
        self.center = Point()
        self.center.x = center[0]
        self.center.y = center[1]
            
    @property
    def center(self):
        return self._center

    @center.setter
    def center(self, d):
        if len(d)> 2:
            print('this is not a 2D point')
        else:
            self._center = d
        
circle = circle([150,100],75)
```

Comment: You should include the full traceback in your question because it will show what line the error is occurring on (as well as other important debugging information).

Comment: if len(d)> 2:

TypeError: object of type 'Point' has no len()

Comment: That's not a full traceback and it's not **in your question** even if it was. The code in your question does not reference `center` so it's not a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making `Circle` do too much work. If its `center` attribute is supposed to be a `Point`, a `Point` should be passed as an argument. Let the caller worry about creating a `Point` from a list of two values, and let `Point` worry about validating the construction of an instance of itself.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, center: Point, radius: int):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius


circle = Circle(Point(150, 100), 75)
```

If you really want something to create a point from a list of values, add a class method to `Point`:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def from_pair(self, p: Iterable[int]):
        try:
            x, y = p
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Argument should contain exactly 2 values")

        return cls(x, y)


circle = Circle(Point.from_pair([150, 100]), 75)
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was trying to implement.

Comment: What do you call the assignment center:Point under the class Circle? Is it the same as creating an object instantiation of class Point?

Comment: The syntax is a function annotation, which is primarily (if not exclusively) used to provide type hints. They are essentially ignored at run time, but tools like `mypy` can be used to perform static type analysis to check if you are passing the correct types of arguments. If nothing else, they serve as documentation for what arguments *should* be passed.

Comment: For example, a call like `Circle("foo", [True, False])` would work at run time (though cause problems later), but `mypy` can flag this as an error.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the explanation.